# Raphael Sphere with shaded color - How to find the hue value of the color

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I got ready function to create a Sphere using Raphael javascript. Below is the code

```
Raphael.fn.ball = function (x, y, r, hue) {
            hue = hue || 0;
            return this.ellipse(x, y, r, r).attr({fill: "r(.3,.25)hsb(" + hue + ", 1, .99)-hsb(" + hue + ", .5, .25)", stroke: "none"});
        };
```

This function creates the sphere with the shaded color inside it. The color is generated using the hue variable passed to it. In the orginal code the value of the hue parameter was taken from 'Math.random()'. But now i want my expected color shade to the sphere. I have Hex codes for the expected code, but I dont know how to get exact hue parameter value to generate same color.

Basically I want to understand -

1. How I can read the expression - "r(.3,.25)hsb(" + hue + ", 1, .99)-hsb(" + hue + ", .5, .25)"?
2. How I can find the hue parameter value to get given color(e.g. - #FEFE31)

Note: I am using HTML and javascript only

Any help is highly appritiated

Comment: I have the exact same issue...

Answer (score 1):

You must convert your Hex color to RGB and then to HSB

```
var hex = "#cc0000";
var rgb = Raphael.getRGB(hex)
var hsb = Raphael.rgb2hsb(rgb)
alert(hsb.h + " is the hue");
```

Keep in mind that RGB doesn't map perfectly to HSB. So, for example, if you set...

```
fill: "hsb(.55, 0%, 0%)"
```

You might get back something different for hue.h, as in pure black the hue doesn't matter.

Comment: So, how would one go about interpreting the color fill string given by OP? `r(.3,.25)hsb(" + hue + ", 1, .99)-hsb(" + hue + ", .5, .25)`

Comment: @fgysin what do you mean by "interpreting"? it's simply a radial gradient as stated in the docs http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr

Answer (score 0):

```
Raphael.fn.ball = function (x, y, r, hue) {
        hue = hue || 0;
        var hex = hue;
        var rgb = Raphael.getRGB(hex)
        var hsb = Raphael.rgb2hsb(rgb)
        return this.ellipse(x, y, r, r).attr({fill: "r(.3,.25)hsb(" + hsb['h'] + ", 1, .99)-hsb(" + hsb['h'] + ", .5, .25)", stroke: "none"});
    };`
```

using @Duopixel's response plus your code, this has been concocted together, i believe this is what you wanted.